# How can i use firebase security roles emulator correctly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to know how to use emulator, i created rule where describe what just users with emails which end "@gmail.com" have access to database

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.email.endsWith('@gmail.com')",
    ".write": "auth.token.email.endsWith('@gmail.com')"
  }
}
```

I use emulator for tests, i added to `Auth token payload` `"email":"test@gmail.com"` and it didn't pass.

[image]

Please help me to test it in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables) documentation for Realtime Database, the [auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#auth) variable contains the token payload if a client is authenticated, or `null` if the client isn't; the [token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken) itself, contains an *email* key. This means that you need to add the *email* key to the token variable in the simulator.

Try writing this in the *Auth token payload* section:

```
{
  "token":{
     "email": "test@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

[image: Sample]